# Using LB_INITSTORAGE with DeleteAllItems?

Tags: visual-c++, memory-management, mfc, listbox

Using Visual C++ with MFC.

Based on this blog, [Speeding up adding items to a combobox or listbox](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/06/10/152612.aspx), I want to call `SendMessage(hwndListBox, LB_INITSTORAGE, cItems, nBytes);` to help reduce flicker of my listbox as I add many items to it.

Basically the technique is to allocate the memory needed for strings all at once using [LB_INITSTORAGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761319.aspx) rather than continually reallocating memory as the listbox grows.

My question is, after I have pre-allocated memory using the LB_INITSTORAGE message, if I then call `DeleteAllItems()` on my listbox control, does this free the memory that I pre-allocated?  In other words, if I want to add the same number of items back to the list box, do I have to send the LB_INITSTORAGE message again?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should send `LB_INITSTORAGE` again.

If I'm not wrong the `DeleteAllItems` call should send a `LB_RESETCONTENT` message. It **may** free the allocated memory.

I'm sure memory isn't released if you send multiple `LB_DELETESTRING` but I'm not sure if this will slow-down too much the process.

Anyway this is more or less an implementation detail, always send `LB_INITSTORAGE` before you add your items: how and when memory is deallocated isn't specified so subject to change.